# Styling a raster on relief shading analysis

Tags: color, terrain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a style file for QGIS from a plain text file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/how-to-create-a-style-file-for-qgis-from-a-plain-text-file)

I have a text file which contains the following data

```
eleva     R      G       B
0   153 255 153
100 179 255 179
200 237 250 230
300 255 242 242
400 255 242 237
```

and I need to convert the text file into a saved color style.How best can I achieve this in QGIS