# Exporting/Printing/Saving CMYK colored map to SVG, PDF, or PRN/EPS file

Tags: qgis, printing, color

I am a beginner using QGIS 2.0.1 on Windows.

Following [Data-defined Styles in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60450/data-defined-styles-in-qgis/60467#60467)
I fill CMYK values on my map layers, but I cannot Export/Print/Save CMYK to SVG, PDF, or PRN/EPS file. I see only RGB values on exported vectors.

How do I export CMYK colored map to prepress software like Illustrator?