# Define polygon colour by a field with CYMK data separated by a comma using QGIS 2.8.2

Tags: qgis-2.8

I have a similar problem to the following post, but the answers to that question did not assist with my problem.

[Data-defined Styles in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60450/data-defined-styles-in-qgis)

I would like to colour the polygons in a shapefile using the BASECOLOUR field of the shapefile's attribute table.  The BASECOLOUR field is a string that specifies the CYMK colours delimited by commas.