# Create points symbology with more than one parameter

Tags: qgis, point, symbology

In QGIS i would like to create symbology for points layer where the symbology will take into account more than one parameter (currently two).
i.e.:
My points layer has street names and house numbers and i would like to have each street with a different symbol and each number with a different color. Each street_name+house_number is unique. I wouldn't mind if distant streets share symbols.

What will be the best way to achieve it in QGIS?
Consider that `Rule-based` symbology is manual and i have many streets, i don't see it as a good solution for this specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in method to automatically classify based on two different symbols with a symbology matrix in the end.

## Data Defined Symbology

QGIS knows the concept of *data defined symbology*. This allows styling different aspects of the symbology each with an expression based on a different attribute.
You can write a `CASE` statement for the line symbology (e.g. dash spaces) based on the street name and an expression that generates color values from the number.
You activate data defined symbology by clicking the small symbol with a letter *E* to the right of the symbology control.

## Python

You can write  some python code that will create the symbology matrix for you and efficiently create a rule based symbology.

Comment: Thanks! i'll check later today. I do know that in ArcGIS you do have an option for that: `Unique Values, Many Fields` with up to 3 fields. I wonder if we just missed this option in QGIS.

Comment: Also - i saw this: http://christopherwesson.azurewebsites.net/2014/03/30/categorising-from-multiple-fields-in-qgis-2/ where he suggests to concatinate strings. I find it not completely suitable for that mission.

Comment: i couldn't find the **data defined symbology** - the only E i found was that sigma like sign that opens the functions window. Can you please guide me?

Comment: It is the sigma sign that opens the function window. See e.g. [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60450/data-defined-styles-in-qgis)

Comment: Weird - i can't see the small window you referenced to, and the sigma is just the `Expression dialog`. It doesn't help much in my case... thanks anyway!

Comment: The screenshot is from an old version. That's why. The "Expression dialog" **is** what you are looking for. The job left for you is to transform the *field value* into a *symbology value* equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! as we discussed previously - it is still a hack like solution for my specific issue.