# Graduated values in symbology based on specific attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm trying to solve the problem I've raised in [Copying graduated scale from polygon to point layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137765)

I've rearranged the attribute table that looks like this:

[image]

Important to notice is that the field "gruppo" is composed by 2 unique attributes: "campione" and "controllo".

What'd like to do now is to create a **graduated** symbology based on an attribute (say "pcb_101") and use the quantile classification.

**BUT** I need that each class of the quantile classification is based only of the "campione" rows of the "gruppo" field.

I tried to use the rule renderer but I noticed that, even if I add the rule `"gruppo" = 'campione'` and add intervals to this rule, the calculation of the quantiles is made using the whole "pcb_101" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

1. setting "gruppo" = 'campione' in General | Query.
2. Then do the classification.
3. Then remove the query again.

Hacky, but might work.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. The trick works..